# HttpClient timeout when requesting accessible webpage

Tags: c#, httpclient, asp.net-core-3.1

We have implemented a simple health check to verify a website is available.
We are facing timeouts in production.

There is a `named HTTP client` registered.
The client sends a simple GET request to a public page of the website. I can reach the page via browser in several seconds.
There is the accept header to accept any content type.
The request completion is set to headers read.
The timeout is set to 30 seconds. The execution takes 30 seconds.
The website is behind a load balancer (CloudFront).

The registration:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient("ClientName", client =>
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
    client.BaseAddress = ServiceUri;
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpLoggingHandler>();
```

The handler:

```cs
// copy response to memory stream
using MemoryStream stream = recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
await response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
```

The response content is written back after the copy. We have multiple clients following the same pattern without an issue.

The call:

```cs
using HttpClient httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(context.Registration.Name);

using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(
                        options.HealthUri,
                        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
                        source.Token); // the token expires in 30 secs
```

Is there any request header missing?

Can be the `HttpLoggingHandler` issue? It tries to read the request/response content and write it to the logs. Can be HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead header causing an issue in this case? Can be the reason in the IHttpClientFactory's internal cache of the message handlers?

> The default System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory implementation may cache the underlying System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler instances to improve performance.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen every time or is it intermittent?  You may be getting credential through a Password server and response from server may be slow.  Does it work with a webbrowser.  Using a sniffer and comparing browser results with your results sometimes finds missing headers.

Comment: Yes, it works in a browser (mentioned in the description). The page is public, so no credentials used. I've checked the headers sent by the browser, but do not see anything. Seems to be intermittent and environment-dependent. I cannot reproduce it in my sandbox, but production has issues.

Comment: Have to compare working and non working.  Intermittent issues are hard to fix.  It probably not your code and a network issue.  Could be a proxy issue.

Comment: I also guess there is an infrastructure issue. I just wanted to ensure we are not missing any recommended headers.

Comment: there are no recommended headers.  Headers are used for negotiations during a connection between the client and server to get a common connection mode.  So headers on the server webpage are compared with the headers in the request.  Also cookies may be used as part of the connection.  Sometimes deleting the cookies get a connection to work.  When changes in code are made the old cookie settings may not be compatible with the newer code.